# is it possible to integrate the angular project and spring boot project in one

Tags: angular, spring-boot, webserver, spring-boot-maven-plugin

https://dzone.com/articles/angular-2-and-spring-boot-development-environment

According to the above link i have created and deployed the server and client side war files individually and its working fine. But I want both the client and server side files to be in one war file  and I should deploy only one war file which include server side and client side files in web serer. Please do the need.

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the reference url(Build and Deployment section), then the "demo-app-server.war" contains both static (angular-code) and java binaries.You can deploy this war file only.